# How to use toBeVisible matcher with React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm using `react-native-testing-library` with `"@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"`.

Looks like `toBeVisible` would only work with ReactJS:

```
const nameField = component.getByPlaceholder("Name");
expect(nameField).toBeVisible();

// Test Error:
● NewCustomerScreen › the basics › encountered a declaration exception

    expect(received).toBeVisible()

    received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement.
    Received has type:  object
    Received has value: {"_fiber": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugID": 26, "_debugIsCurrentlyTiming": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": null, "alternate": null, "child": [FiberNode], "childExpirationTime": 0, "contextDependencies": null, "effectTag": 133, "elementType": [Function Component], "expirationTime": 0, "firstEffect": null, "index": 1, "key": null, "lastEffect": null, "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": null, "mode": 0, "nextEffect": [FiberNode], "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": [Function ref], "return": [FiberNode], "sibling": null, "stateNode": [Component], "tag": 1, "type": [Function Component], "updateQueue": null}}
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

[Here](https://github.com/testing-library/native-testing-library-docs/blob/c36d3f91aa64d02556344262bd44c5dae7cb2803/website/versioned_docs/version-2.0.0/ecosystem-jest-native.md) you can see the explanation related to this.

```js
import { render } from 'react-native-testing-library';
...
const { getByPlaceholder } = render(
  <View>
    <TextInput placeholder="Name"  />
  </View>
);
..
expect(getByPlaceholder("Name")).toBeVisible();
```

**toBeVisible Example**

```js
<View>
  <View testID="not-empty">
    <Text testID="empty" />
  </View>
  <Text testID="visible">Visible Example</Text>
</View>;

expect(queryByTestId(baseElement, 'not-empty')).not.toBeEmpty();
expect(getByText(baseElement, 'Visible Example')).toBeVisible();
```

Comment: From looking at your link, it seems like the key here is to use `jest-native`. However, when I `import "@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect";`, I still get an error: `    TypeError: expect(...).toBeVisible is not a function`.

Comment: I  think it can't be used in placeholders.

Comment: This doesn't work either: `expect(queryByTestId(component, "payment-webview")).toBeVisible();`. Also, your exact code raised exceptions on simply calling `getByText` without attaching it to anything.

Comment: This is the code written in the official document. I can't see your code, so I don't know the problem, but I think it's the wrong way.

Comment: ToBeVisible is not a jest matcher in in jest-native/extend-expect you will have to create your own or use the props to check visibility.